# Sum of numbers from dynamic inner text using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to get the total sum of values having class addition1:::

HTML CODE is

```
<tr >
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Inr</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php if($inr!='')echo co($inr);else echo "0.00";?>     </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">ROE</td>
  <td  class="heading" ><span class="addition1"><?php if($inr!='')echo co($inr);else echo "0.00";?> </span>   </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Usd</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php if($usd!='')echo co($usd);else echo "0.00";?> </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe11" type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td class="heading1"  style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <span class="addition1">
            <?php if($usd!='')echo co($usd);else echo "0.00";?>  </span>  
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Gbp</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php if($gbp!='')echo co($gbp);else echo "0.00";?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe12" type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td class="heading2" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <span class="addition1"><?php if($gbp!='')echo co($gbp);else echo "0.00";?></span>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Eur</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php if($eur!='')echo co($eur); else echo "0.00";?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe13"  type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td  class="heading3" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
   <span class="addition1"> <?php if($eur!='')echo co($eur); else echo "0.00";?></span>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Other</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php if($other!='')echo co($other);else echo "0.00";?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe14" type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td class="heading4" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <span class="addition1"><?php if($other!='')echo (co($other));else echo "0.00";?>    </span>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Jquery Code is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tables tbody>tr>td>input.heading#roe13').change(function() {
        var k = $('#roe13').val(); 
         $('#tables tbody>tr>td.heading3').text(function(i,v) {
            v= v.replace(/,/g, ''),
            asANumber = +v;
            x=Math.round(parseFloat(v*k)*100) / 100;
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

        });
    });


$('#tables tbody>tr>td>input.heading#roe11').change(function() {
        var k = $('#roe11').val(); 
        $('#tables tbody>tr>td.heading1').text(function(i,v) {
            v= v.replace(/,/g, ''),
            asANumber = +v;                 
            x1=Math.round(parseFloat(v*k)*100) / 100;
            return x1.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });

$('#tables tbody>tr>td>input.heading#roe12').change(function() {
        var k = $('#roe12').val(); 
        $('#tables tbody>tr>td.heading2').text(function(i,v) {
            v= v.replace(/,/g, ''),
            asANumber = +v;                 
            x2=Math.round(parseFloat(v*k)*100) / 100;
            return x2.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });

$('#tables tbody>tr>td>input.heading#roe14').change(function() {
        var k = $('#roe14').val(); 
        $('#tables tbody>tr>td.heading4').text(function(i,v) {
            v= v.replace(/,/g, ''),
            asANumber = +v;                 
            x3=Math.round(parseFloat(v*k)*100) / 100;
            return x3.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });


$('#tables tbody>tr').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        var regex = /\((\d+)\)/g;
        $('span.addition1').each(function() {       
            matches = $(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''); alert(matches);
            if( !isNaN( matches ) ){        
                sum += parseFloat(matches);
            }           
        });
    }); 
});
```

Class name in td can't be changed . I am trying to get the sum of values having class addition1. On running this code, 1 value is getting skipped, e.g. If I change a value say x1 then result generated due to x1 will be skipped in addition.
Please help me out.

Comment: `var matches = regex.exec($(this).val());` : You can't retrieve the value contained in a `div` with `val()`

Comment: If i change it to .text : 
var matches = regex.exec($(this).text());-----result is same

Comment: It is worth noting that you can have more than one class on an element. For example: `<td class="class1 class2">..</td>`.

Comment: It is also worth noting that a lot of your function code is repeated. A generic function with a target element passed in could replace the top four change functions.

Comment: Actually I have just started using jquery that's why I don't  know much ways to get the desired result which makes my code lengthy and disorganized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in jquery are 0-based if you want the first value of matches use `matches[0]`.

Don't put div's directly inside tr's. I'd recommend a `span class="addition1"` inside each of the td's and only round the floats you wish add.

This way you can `parsefloat()` first and then perform a NaN check after, stripping out all the regex stuff:

td code:

```
<td>..(<span class="addition1">1,230.0</span>)..</td>
```

jquery loop code:

```
$('span.addition1').each(function() {
 var floatVal = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g,""));
 if(!isNaN(floatVal)) {        
  sum += floatVal;
 }         
});
```

Use `$(this).text()` not `.val()`.

Comment: using span it started giving NAN  and I am using a value like 2,456::
that's why i m using regex.

Comment: then strip the commas out before parsing.. see updated code. As it is your regex is not matching on commas anyway so would return 2 as the first match in the above case.

Comment: I just saw the brackets in your regex.. This and the comma is why you are getting no matches. `/\(1,234)\/` will not match `/\(\d+\)/` but will match `/\([\d,]+\)/`.. but seriously use a replace and then a `parsefloat()` and put the span around the value but inside the brackets.

Comment: using a replace(",","") only provides 1230 in case of 1,230. But in case of 2,345,678 it only returns 2345 so I have used replace(/,/g, '')) for this purpose. Everything is good in this code except one value, which is changing dynamically, is skipped every time.

Comment: Good spot on the replace functionality! Hmm.. which value is changing dynamically and how is it done?

Comment: I have edited my code, now you can check there how the values are changing. Now when I change any value say x1 then result generated due to x1 will be skipped in addition.

Comment: It looks like your functions set the text value of the `td` rather than the inner `span` (with the addition class). This will remove the `span` and cause it to be missed. Append the `span.addition1` to the selectors ending `.headingN` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).val() refers to the value of the div.addition1, which does not have a value.

You are trying to nest td's inside a div which is not allowed for. If you cannot edit the TD's to give them a class you will have to use some other way of selecting them, like every eight TD or something similar.

Comment: If i change it to .text : var matches = regex.exec($(this).text());-----result is same

Comment: It's still not valid HTML to nest block element like DIV inside a table structure. If you can put the div inside the TD you will be fine.

Comment: Was gonna plus one your answer until i read 'like every eight TD or something similar'!

Comment: well, it wouldn't be pretty but the obvious pretty solutions (class on appropriate TD, etc) seems to be out of reach

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<tr >
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Inr</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php echo $inr!=''?co($inr):"0.00";?>     </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">ROE</td><div class="addition1">
  <td  class="heading" ><?php echo $inr!=''?co($inr):"0.00";?>    </td></div>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Usd</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php echo $usd!=''?co($usd):"0.00";?> </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe11" type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td class="heading1"  style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <?php echo $usd!=''?co($usd):"0.00";?>    
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Gbp</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php echo $gbp!=''?co($gbp):"0.00";?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe12" type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td class="heading2" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <?php echo $gbp!=''?co($gbp):"0.00";?>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Eur</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php echo $eur!=''?co($eur):"0.00";?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe13"  type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td  class="heading3" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <?php echo $eur!=''?co($eur):"0.00";?>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="heading">Total Other</td>
  <td align="right" class="heading"><?php echo $other!=''?co($other):"0.00";?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input name="roe1" id="roe14" type="text" class="heading" value="1" style="width:50px" /></td>
  <td class="heading4" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: bold;">
    <?php echo $other!=''?co($other):"0.00";?>    
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
$('table tr').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $.each($('tr td input'), function() {
        var nextCol = $(this).parent().next("td").text();
        if( nextCol && ! isNaN( nextCol ) ){        
            sum += parseFloat(nextCol, 10);
        }         
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

Just Addition:

```
$('table tr').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $.each($('addition1'), function() {
        var nextCol = $(this).text();
        if( nextCol && ! isNaN( nextCol ) ){        
            sum += parseFloat(nextCol, 10);
        }         
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

Comment: Change `var matches = regex.exec($(this).val());` to `var matches = regex.exec($(this).text());`

Comment: I have modified your code, this now calculates the column next to the input box

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about 'the column next to the input box'. This could start introducing extra unwanted values and is rather restrictive, I feel a more generic solution involving a specific class is more appropriate.

Comment: If you are using the spans like in your question, you can use the `Just Addition` block of code and this sould do the working out for you.